# Attempted to load interface "CommandSubscriber" from namespace "MongoDB\Driver\Monitoring"

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-odm, symfony5

I have Symfony 5 project and just following the instructions to install the DoctrineMongoDBBundle package, and I'm receiving te following error,

Attempted to load interface "CommandSubscriber" from namespace "MongoDB\Driver\Monitoring".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

/vendor/doctrine/mongodb-odm/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/APM/CommandLoggerInterface.php (line 9)

I have the following versions of mongodb and doctrine running.

- doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": 4.1
- mongodb/mongodb": 1.6

Also the php driver installed through Pecl (Version 1.7.4)

Anyone got any ideas to what I'm missing?

Comment: Did you tried clear the cache with `bin/console cache:clear -e prod` command?

Answer (score 5):

If it helps anyone in the future, whilst the MongoDB Driver was installed, I needed to restart PHP FPM, that fixed it.